# How do I stop listening to database changes in Firebase Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a web application that is built in Nextjs and uses Firebase Firestore for storing data. Everything else is fine with the app, but tools that test website speed give it horrible grades, because requests to Firestore never finish even though the app has already gotten all the data it needs on the frontend.

My code for fetching data:

```
const getData = () => {
        const q = query(collection(firestore, "data"), where("published", "==", true));
        const data = [];
        const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            data.push({id: doc.id, ...doc.data()});
          });
        });

        return data
}
```

The function for returning data works fine and everything is returned quickly, but the request keeps hanging without finishing. I've attached a screenshot captured from Chrome devtools.
[Image: "CAUTION: request is not finished yet!"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHmgP.png)
How do I get Firestore to stop listening for changes in the database?

I've tried looking for solutions everywhere online and found some people saying that using "const unsubscribe = ..." to define the query and later calling "unsubscribe();" would work, but calling "unsubscribe();" prevents the function from returning the data at all for some reason.

Comment: Do you need to fetch data only once ?

Comment: Ideally I could trigger data fetching whenever necessary and it would get the data in its current state at that given time without keeping the connection alive. So for example I could get data when the user lands on the main page and then refresh it when they navigate back to the main page (if they move around in between)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch data only once, then use `getDocs()` instead:

```js
const getData = async () => {
  const q = query(collection(firestore, "data"), where("published", "==", true));
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
  return querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({id: doc.id, ...doc.data()}))
}
```

Unlike `onSnapshot()`, `getDocs()` won't listen for realtime updates. You can just call `getData()` again to reload the data. You can learn more about fetching data from Firestore in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it didn't help... I've tried going through the documentation and trying different things, but there's still that strange Firebase request that doesn't finish. I've also narrowed it down to that specific function, since the problem disappears when I remove the only component that needs that data.

Comment: @Markus did you try restart your dev server or clearing any cache ?

Comment: Yes, I did. Neither restarting my local dev server nor deploying the modified function to Vercel for live testing helped. Fetching still works fine, but that one request prevents me from getting any meaningful Lighthouse data.

Don't know if this helps, but the request url begins with: https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen/channel?database=projects%2F{my project name}%2Fdatabases%2F(default)&gsessionid=...

Comment: @Markus is this on Github by chance? or can you atleast share relevant components that can help clone that issue,

Comment: While building a light demo app I could've shared with you I happened to try using Nextjs' "getStaticProps()", which for some reason solved my problem. Using SWR or fetching data inside useEffect() seemed to cause the request to hang. Thanks for help anyways :)